# Kivy Video class rtsp stream not working on other pc

Tags: python, kivy, python-3.7

I have created an app that displays rtsp streams in Kivy grid view. It works just fine on my computer, but when I deploy it to another PC everything works up until the video needs to be playing in the grid (i just get white squares in the lower left of the tile). I strongly feel that there is a package I need to download that Kivy Documentation does not mention.

I have pip installed all kivy dependencies, Cython, and Pillow on the other PC.

I would like to see video in each block as I do on the PC that I built the app on

### No RTSP Stream Coming Through

[image: No RTSP Stream Coming Through]

***Update: (On the other PC (mini PC)) I uninstalled Python 3.7.3, reinstalled it, installed kivy in the proper order according to their install for windows documentation, and installed Cython. This got it working but now some the text is missing in the app. Also, I am getting multiple .dll errors (libopus-0.dll and libgstopus.dll) I tried removing gstreamer from the python share folder and that got it back to just showing white boxes.

Comment: The white box indicates that it is loading (looping). If you replace `Video` with `VideoPlayer`, it will show the loading gif. What are the differences between both PCs e.g. Python version, processor speed, memory, OS, etc.? Have you installed gstreamer, sdl2, angle, and glew?

Comment: On my PC I have 64GB RAM, 2TB HDD, Intel Xeon 3 GHz, Python 3.7.1 and the other PC is a mini PC 28.2 GB HHD, Intel Celleron 1.10 GHz, 4 GB RAM, and Python 3.7.3. Also, yes I installed all dependencies.

Comment: Your app has four videos running simultaneously. Try running with just one video in the other PC.

Comment: ikolim -I tried using just one video and it did not work. I gave it ~10 minutes to try and load.